# Gradient zero a.e on the the zero set

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces

In Brezis Functional Analysis Page 314 Point 4 it is given that for u in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ where $\Omega$ is any open set then $\nabla u=0$ a.e on the set where $\{u(x)=k\}$, k is a constant.

How does one prove this fact.

Comment: The result can be generalized, $\{u=k\}$ could be replaced by $\{x; u(x)\in A\}$ where $A$ is a zero Lebesgue measure set. This kind of result is crucial to obtain that $\nabla T(u)=T'(u)\nabla u$ a.e., known as a result of Stampacchia, and under conditions on $T$. You can find a proof in a paper of Boccardo-Murat, http://purl.pt/3028/1/j-5293-b-vol41-fasc1-4-art41_PDF/j-5293-b-vol41-fasc1-4-art41_PDF_01-B-R0300/j-5293-b-vol41-fasc1-4-art41_0000_capa1-562_t01-B-R0300.pdf or in a course (see pages 5-8) of Droniou http://www-gm3.univ-mrs.fr/cours/fichiers/cours-dea.pdf. (in French, sorry)

Answer (score 4):

Let $A = \{u = k\}$.  Let $\varphi_n : \mathbb{R} \to [0,1]$ be a smooth function supported inside $[k-\frac{1}{n}, k+\frac{1}{n}]$, with $\varphi_n(k)=1$.  Then $\varphi_n(u) \to 1_A$, pointwise and boundedly, so for each $i$, since $\partial_i u \in L^p$, dominated convergence gives $\varphi_n(u) \partial_i u \to 1_A \partial_i u$ in $L^p$ norm.

Let $\psi_n(t) = \int_{-\infty}^t \phi_n(s)\,ds$ so that $\psi_n' = \varphi_n$; note $\psi_n \to 0$ uniformly.  Let $v \in C^\infty_c(\Omega)$ be arbitrary.  By the chain rule and integration by parts we have
$$\int (\varphi_n(u) \partial_i u) v = \int \partial_i (\psi_n(u)) v = -\int \psi_n(u) \partial_i v.$$
As $n \to \infty$ the left side converges to $\int (1_A \partial_i u) v$ and the right side converges to $0$.  So $\int (1_A \partial_i u) v = 0$.  Since $v$ was arbitrary and $C^\infty_c(\Omega)$ is dense in $L^q(\Omega)$, we conclude that $1_A \partial_i u = 0$ almost everywhere, which is the desired statement.

(Self-plagiarism disclosure: this proof is the very same argument as Lemma 7.4 of [these notes of mine](http://arxiv.org/abs/1607.03591); I think I learned the argument from Nualart's *The Malliavin Calculus and Related Topics*, but it seems to be pretty standard.)